# How to to search for an multiple words in a file using regular expressions

Tags: perl

I need a little help , I am new to Perl. If for example in a file named `out.txt` which contains the following data:

```
Apple Banana potato
Ashok is a boy
Apple is good
```

ALL three sentences in three different lines I need to search the first occurence of `apple` and `Ashok` in the file and print the 3rd word in that line ie "`potato`", "`a`" . And also print `0` if it doesn't find the word. How can I do this? Please Help :) TIA

Comment: What did you try? Where did you get stuck? What issues are you facing?

Comment: I don't know how to use regular expressions properly would be helpful if u can write a sample code

Comment: Start by reading `perldoc perlretut` and after that feel free to ask any questions that remain unanswered after having done due diligence, and after having written as much code as you can on your own, to provide us with context.

Comment: @ChankeyPathak I am not able to post my code here..... Any help with the code would be greatful

Comment: @ChankeyPathak Please it is little urgent... If u can provide the sample code on it code it will be useful

Comment: @ChankeyPathak How to print a zero if it doesn't search that word? I am giving an else condition but no output

Comment: else 
{
print "0";
}
this isn't working

Comment: @ChankeyPathak I just want the first search of Apple ... not multiple searches.. How can i do that? Also only if it searches exact word Apple .. if ther is a word Apples it shouldn't Search

Answer (score 0):

```
use strict;

my %uniquekey=();
open (FH, "out.txt");
while (<FH>)
{
    my $line=$_;
    if($line=~m/([\w]+)\s([\w]+)\s([\w]+).*$/i || $line=~m/([\w]+)\s([\w]+).*$/i)
    {
        my $first=$1;
        my $third=$3;

        if($third eq ""){$third=0}
        if(!exists($uniquekey{$first})){
            $uniquekey{$first}=$first;
            print "$first $third\n";
        }
        elsif($third ne "")
        {
            print "$third\n";
        }

    }
}
close FH;
```

Comment: I want the code to search the word in the file not in a line... and print the 2 nd word in that line.. if it doesn't find the word in the file(not the line) print 0

Comment: Its reading from the file only, we are getting line by line in while loop. place the file in same path where you executing the perl file.